ELRS: Is it possible to save the last position of the sticks after signal loss?
I have previously used TBS Crossfire. Using the TBS Agent, you can configure failsafe mode - Fs. Pos, in which, in case of signal loss, the last position of the sticks will be saved. Is it possible to do this on ELRS?
